# Servant: a callback that runs on any request

Tags: haskell, servant

I use [Servant](https://www.servant.dev). I need to set some callback function that will be executed on every request and **it will forward the request processing/handling further** (to other handler, as if this callback did not exist at all). I need it to change some `IORef MyGlobalState` in this callback. How to do it? Some example? Sure, I can call it explicitly in all handlers' bodies but maybe there is some right/canonical way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example server:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant
import Servant.API
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Data.IORef
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

type API = "one" :> Get '[PlainText] String :<|> "two" :> Get '[PlainText] String

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = return "1\n" :<|> return "2\n"

app :: Application
app = serve api server

main = run 3000 app
```

The `app` value is a [WAI `Application`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-19.20/wai-3.2.3/Network-Wai.html#t:Application), defined by:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

Conceptually, an `Application` accepts a `Request`, and invokes a callback on its `Response`.  WAI supports the concept of `Middleware` which can wrap an application, allowing preprocessing of every request and post-processing of every response in the IO monad:

```
type Middleware = Application -> Application
```

So, you can write a piece of middleware to update an `IORef` on every received request like so:

```
counter :: IORef Int -> Middleware
counter cref = convert

  where
    convert :: Application -> Application  -- AKA Middleware
    convert oldapp = newapp

      where
        newapp :: Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived  -- AKA Application
        newapp req respond = do
          n <- atomicModifyIORef cref (\n' -> (n'+1,n'+1))
          putStrLn $ "Request #" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ showRequest req
          oldapp req respond

        showRequest req = C.unpack (requestMethod req) ++ " " ++ C.unpack (rawPathInfo req)
```

I've broken this up into separate functions to make it clear how the middleware is constructed piece by piece, but the definition of `counter` can be simplified to the equivalent:

```
counter :: IORef Int -> Middleware
counter cref oldapp req respond
  = do n <- atomicModifyIORef cref (\n' -> (n'+1,n'+1))
       putStrLn $ "Request #" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ showRequest req
       oldapp req respond

  where
    showRequest req = C.unpack (requestMethod req) ++ " " ++ C.unpack (rawPathInfo req)
```

Now, all you need to do is wrap your `app` with the middleware in `main`:

```
main = do
  cref <- newIORef (0 :: Int)
  run 3000 $ counter cref app
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant
import Servant.API
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Data.IORef
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

type API = "one" :> Get '[PlainText] String :<|> "two" :> Get '[PlainText] String

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

server :: Server API
server = return "1\n" :<|> return "2\n"

app :: Application
app = serve api server

counter :: IORef Int -> Middleware
counter cref oldapp req respond
  = do n <- atomicModifyIORef cref (\n' -> (n'+1,n'+1))
       putStrLn $ "Request #" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ showRequest req
       oldapp req respond

  where
    showRequest req = C.unpack (requestMethod req) ++ " " ++ C.unpack (rawPathInfo req)

main = do
  cref <- newIORef (0 :: Int)
  run 3000 $ counter cref app
```